# collect iFrame DOM Events

Tags: javascript, iframe

I try for two days to find a good answer but without success.

How can I run `JavaScript` DOM events in `iFrame`?

My goal is to collect data like `onMouseMove` on `iFrame` and retrieve this data.

For example:

When I recognized I'm in `iFrame` then I need to fire DOM events and collecting the data from the DOM events and retrieve the data to the parent page.

There are no cross-domain issues.

If anyone has a good explanation it will be great, because I want to understand perfectly how it's done.

Thanks In advance for all the answers.

Comment: Possible Duplicate. Please see -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: You have to try something, then we can tell you any problems with it. Otherwise, we don't know which part you're having trouble with. You should never ask someone to write it for you at SO

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
const receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow; // this is your iframe

receiver.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  // Do something
});
```

Comment: What is the 'message' in the 'addEventListener' and what is the 'typeName'?
Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more simple approach.  If this doesn't work I can help explain my last solution

Comment: The event name is `mousemove`, the iframe is not where you should register listeners, but on the [contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

Comment: Hi Mark, first of all, thanks, a second I want to tell what I understand. When The page finish loading I want to check each time the mouse moving if it's inside the iFrame or not (I do it by this condition --> window.location!=window.parent.location). If the mouse is inside the iFrame I add an event listener and then collect all my relevant data, I can save the data in a global object array. do you this is correct? just the way I thinking, because tomorrow I need to explain at work how theoretically how it's work.

Comment: The 'mousemove' event listener on the iframe like my code states would fire an event when the mouse is moved inside of the iframe.  You could do all of your tracking from inside of this theoretically.

Comment: Feel free to select my answer as correct if this worked for you.  Thanks!